# Receiving anonymous type from a method, knowing its members at compile time

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, static-typing, static-binding

I know there are a lot of questions about C# anonymous types, but none of them answers me. I also know that you can return anonymous types, either assigning the result of the method to a `dynamic` object or casting it as [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx) by Jon Skeet states, but in both cases you need to know which are the members of the anonymous object, so why can't we have a sort of keyword named `anonymous` which allow us to do things like this:

```
anonymous F()
{
    ...
    return new { a = 5, b = "some string" };
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
anonymous a = F();
```

but having static typing?
I mean, why isn't the compiler able to know statically which are the members of the anonymous object `F` method returns, and so give me intellisense?

Comment: I'm sure the compiler *could* do that, but is it really worth the effort? We have named types, and dynamics, and ExpandoObject. What is the strong case for supporting anonymous types like that that can't already be solved using one of those?

Comment: okay, what if I do an `if` statement and return `new { a = 5 }` in 1st case and `new { b = "some thing" }` in 2nd.

Comment: what would the compiler do if there is a condition in the method and the method can return 2 different anonymous object?

Comment: @vcsjones: `ExpandoObject` uses a dictionary, it makes dynamic binding, which is slower than static binding, besides you can't get intellisense. What if my application needs for some reason a certain kind of high performance? It definitely wouldn't be good using `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: @e.campver then use a named type. Honestly

Comment: @ArturUdod: You are right!!! I don't know how I didn't think of that. Someone gave me an answer identical to yours, but you did it first, please make if as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I won't mind if you accept @Pako 's answer )

Comment: Please heed Jon Skeet's advice: *Please do not use this "technique" in your code. If you do, at least don't mention my name anywhere near it.  --Jon Skeet*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would you stop than from doing something like this:

```
anonymous F()
{
     if (something) return new { a = 5 };
     else return new { b = 1, z = "asdf" };
}
```

How is compiler supposed to know which type is returned then? Should it limit you at design time with error messages that those anonymous types are not the same? Is it worth the effort? You can use `dynamic` for such cases or create actual classes if needed - to make code clear.

Comment: And also, take a look at this: http://ideone.com/F8QwHY and this http://ideone.com/hDTcxX. In first case compiler re-uses 1 class and in 2nd case it decides to generate 2 classes.

Comment: So I even doubt if compiler in current state can provide such error-checking at design time. Once you change the order of fields you get 2 incompatible return types.